# Node Express Mongoose : Problem with Number value Undefined

Tags: node.js, express

In my app, I have a counter collection in mongoDB.

POST and GET are OK.

But the PUT doesn't update counter values :

```
exports.setCounter = (req, res, next) => {
    var query = Counter.where({ cid: 'supercounter' })
    console.log('req body setCounter  ' + req.body.value);
    Counter.find().then(

        (counter) => {
            console.log(counter)
            switch (req.body.value) {
                case 'aco': // add a company 
                    counter.numco = counter.numco + 1;
                    break;
                case 'dco': // delete a company
                    counter.numco = counter.numco - 1;
                    break;
                case 'ausco': // add a company user
                    console.log(counter.numusco);
                    counter.numusco = counter.numusco + 1;
                    console.log(counter.numusco);
                    break;
                case 'dusco': // delete a company user
                    counter.numusco = counter.numusco - 1;
                    break;


            }
            query.updateOne(counter).then(
                () => {
                    res.status(201).json({
                        message: 'Counter updated successfully!'
                    });
                }
            ).catch(
                (error) => {
                    res.status(400).json({
                        error: error
                    });
                }
            )
        }
    )
    };
```

All counters are as Numbers.
I send the value 'ausco' but didnt work.

Here is the nodemon console log :

[image]

Someone know why i get Undefined and NaN ?

Thanks for your Help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `console.log(counter)` is outputting an array.

When accessing e.g. `console.log(counter.numusco);` it should be `console.log(counter[0].numusco)`;

EDIT: clarity for "why" exactly

`undefined` is being output because the property numusco does not exist on the array object

`NaN` then came because math operations (e.g. +1) with `undefined` result in not-a-number

Comment: Exact ^^ you're correct I used .find instead of .findOne ^^ Thank you a lot ^^